# Randomizing predictions with ARIMA model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, forecasting, arima

I made a synthetic data generator with the SARIMA model based on an input sample. The SARIMA model predicts time series of the length of the original input and I must say that it works quite well. I wonder if there is a way to get n number of time series similar to the predicted time series using this model.

Comment: You can [simulate](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.simulate.html). A minimal working example would probably lead to more specific answers.

Comment: I used pmdarima package with autoarima that offers gridsearch for hiperparameters then just simple predict(n_periods).